Google Sheet multiple rows into single row based on a specific column
Im trying to achieve the below. Anyone has suggestions on how to do with google sheet.
Idea is that i have multiple Owners and helpers for each Customer Name, each of them on a seperate row. I want to combine the information into 1 row / customer name where all the Owners/Helpers name will appear on that single row.
What I have:



Cust
Name
Role




Apple
john
Owner


Apple
mark
Helper


Apple
elise
Owner


Apple
Bob
Helper


Apple
Franky
Helper


Banana
Alice
Owner


Banana
Mendy
Helper


Banana
Marius
Helper


Orange
Alex
Owner


Orange
Gareth
Owner


Orange
Jones
Helper



What I like to get is:



Cust
Owner1
Helper1
Owner2
Helper2
Owner3
Helper3




Apple
john
mark
elise
Bob

Franky


Banana
Alice
Mendy

Marius




Orange
Alex
Jones
Gareth






Example of what I have and the end result
Tried using Query and Group by, but it doesnt really work because the data is strings and not values

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read tag descriptions before using them: "Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead." Thus, please [edit] your post to share your data as a markdown text table, see the formatting help. Also, please do add a [mre], i.e. your attempts using Query and Group by, so that we can help you debug your formulae.


You may try:
=map(unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(Σ,hstack(Σ,ifna(let(Λ,lambda(x,filter(B:B,A:A=Σ,C:C=x)),torow(hstack(Λ("Owner"),Λ("Helper"))))))))



Thank you. this seem to cover properly what im looking for

One more question, if I have a also another column between column A and Column B (lets say a customer description column) that I also want to insert into the table on the right.
So ill have on the left table: (Cust, Description, Name, Role) and the final table should look like:
Cust, Description, Owner1, Helper1, Owner2, Helper2 ...
And this description is directly tied to the Cust, how do i also add it to the final table ?

Share a test sheet showcasing your input and expected output(filled manually)
